# List.jsx:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'destination')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

actually i am new to react so its too difficult for me to solve this error . i am trying to display list of hotels in a separate page by using "/hotels" but when i type this it is showing error that i have mentioned down there also i tried set value of destination but it is'nt worked. but after /hotels i have given a route path of id as well so /hotels/id it is working well but /hotels its not working it showing blank page and errors.

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './pages/home/Home';
import List from './pages/list/List';
import Hotel from './pages/hotel/Hotel';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/hotels' element={<List />} />
        <Route path='/hotels/:id' element={<Hotel />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

List.js

```
import './list.css';
import Navbar from '../../components/navbar/Navbar';
import Header from '../../components/header/Header';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import { DateRange } from 'react-date-range';
import SearchItem from '../../components/searchItem/SearchItem';

const List = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [destination, setDestination] = useState(location.state.destination);
  const [date, setDate] = useState(location.state.date);
  const [openDate, setOpenDate] = useState(false);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(location.state.options);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Header type='list' />
      <div className='listContainer'>
        <div className='listWrapper'>
          <div className='listSearch'>
            <h1 className='lsTitle'>Search</h1>
            <div className='lsItem'>
              <label>Destination</label>
              <input placeholder={destination} type='text' />
            </div>
            <div className='lsItem'>
              <label>Check-in Date</label>
              <span onClick={() => setOpenDate(!openDate)}>{`${format(
                date[0].startDate,
                'MM/dd/yyyy'
              )} to ${format(date[0].endDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy')}`}</span>
              {openDate && (
                <DateRange
                  onChange={(item) => setDate([item.selection])}
                  minDate={new Date()}
                  ranges={date}
                />
              )}
            </div>
            <div className='lsItem'>
              <label>Options</label>
              <div className='lsOptions'>
                <div className='lsOptionItem'>
                  <span className='lsOptionText'>
                    Min price <small>per night</small>
                  </span>
                  <input type='number' className='lsOptionInput' />
                </div>
                <div className='lsOptionItem'>
                  <span className='lsOptionText'>
                    Max price <small>per night</small>
                  </span>
                  <input type='number' className='lsOptionInput' />
                </div>
                <div className='lsOptionItem'>
                  <span className='lsOptionText'>Adult</span>
                  <input
                    type='number'
                    min={1}
                    className='lsOptionInput'
                    placeholder={options.adult}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className='lsOptionItem'>
                  <span className='lsOptionText'>Children</span>
                  <input
                    type='number'
                    min={0}
                    className='lsOptionInput'
                    placeholder={options.children}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className='lsOptionItem'>
                  <span className='lsOptionText'>Room</span>
                  <input
                    type='number'
                    min={1}
                    className='lsOptionInput'
                    placeholder={options.room}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button>Search</button>
          </div>
          <div className='listResult'>
            <SearchItem />
            <SearchItem />
            <SearchItem />
            <SearchItem />
            <SearchItem />
            <SearchItem />
            <SearchItem />
            <SearchItem />
            <SearchItem />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;


and the errors are
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'destination')
 at List (List.jsx:12:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25750:1
```

Comment: i think problem is at `useState(location.state.destination)`; i think you should check value of `location.state`

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned `location.state.destination` I'm expecting the routing is done programmatically using `useNavigate` and you are sending data.

```
const [destination, setDestination] = useState(location.state.destination);
```

ensure you are sending data like this

```
navigate('/hotels',{state:{location:"USA",date:xyz,options:{}}});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are trying to go to the /hotels page directly without giving any input to your search boxes. As you are initializing the state values using your search box values, you should fill the search boxes and then use the search button to go the /hotels page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).